# Failing bulk insert data from Pandas dataframe into Sybase database table using to_sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, sybase

The purpose of my below code is to get data from a restful service, normalize it, store it in dataframe with necessary columns and then finally load it in Sybase table using Pandas' `to_sql`.

Error :

> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 467, in do_executemany
> cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Incorrect syntax near ','.\n (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO dbo.contract_test ("CONTRACT_ID", "EXCHANGE_ID", "CURRENCY", "TRADING_CODE") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (('0050/TAIEX', 'TAIEX', 'TWD', 0), ('035420/KORE', 'KORE', 'KRW', 0), ('0TL/LIF', 'LIF', 'NOK', 1), ('100FTSE/LIF', 'LIF', 'GBP', 0), ('101FTSE/LIF', 'LIF', 'GBP', 0), ('10STAT/OM', 'OM', 'SEK', 0), ('10TB/KFX', 'KFX', 'KRW', 0), ('10TBA/KFX', 'KFX', 'KRW', 0)  ... displaying 10 of 4525 total bound parameter sets ...  ('ZURF/DTB', 'DTB', 'CHF', 0), ('ZX/NYCE', 'NYCE', 'USD', 0))]

> Process finished with exit code 1

Code :

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import *               
from sqlalchemy.connectors.pyodbc import *             
from sqlalchemy import create_engine                       
import urllib.request as request                  
import json                         
import pandas as pd                      
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize, DataFrame      
           
response = request.urlopen('http://tfsdscsw5XX/mdsclass/CONTFUTURES--O.json')            
output=response.read()                              
data=json.loads(output)           
df=json_normalize(data)                           
df1=(df[['CONTRACT_ID','EXCHANGE_ID','CURRENCY','TRADING_CODE']])                
df2=pd.DataFrame(df1)           
print(df2)                
print(df2.CONTRACT_ID)          
            
connector =  PyODBCConnector()                 
url = make_url("sybase+pyodbc://myhost/mydatabase?driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise&port=2306")              
print(connector.create_connect_args(url))                         
engine=create_engine(url)

#it is failing here**
df2.to_sql("contract_test",engine,index=False,if_exists="append",schema="dbo")   

response.close()
```

Sample of data in dataframe df2 :

```
      CONTRACT_ID EXCHANGE_ID CURRENCY  TRADING_CODE
0      0050/TAIEX       TAIEX      TWD             0
1     035420/KORE        KORE      KRW             0
2         0TL/LIF         LIF      NOK             1
3     100FTSE/LIF         LIF      GBP             0
4     101FTSE/LIF         LIF      GBP             0
```

Table contract_test definition :

```
CREATE TABLE contract_test (
    CONTRACT_ID char(12) NOT NULL,
    EXCHANGE_ID char(12),
    CURRENCY char(4) NOT NULL,
    TRADING_CODE smallint
) 
GO
```

Please help as to how can this be resolved ? I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may simply be the incompatibilities of Python database APIs. Pandas' `to_sql` is really running an `executemany()` call from `pyodbc`. This module is more popularly used with SQL Server especially in implementation with SQLAlchemy. However, integration with Sybase is not fully supported. As mentioned on the SQLAlchemy Sybase [docs page](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sybase.html):

> **Note**
>
> The Sybase dialect within SQLAlchemy is not currently supported. It is
> not tested within continuous integration and is likely to have many
> issues and caveats not currently handled. Consider using the external
> dialect instead.

Specifically, `executemany` appears to be running multiple `VALUES` row inserts which is supported in SQL Server but not Sybase (even though both dialects are variants of TSQL with known history of connection):

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.contract_test ("CONTRACT_ID", "EXCHANGE_ID", "CURRENCY", "TRADING_CODE") 
VALUES ('0050/TAIEX', 'TAIEX', 'TWD', 0), 
       ('035420/KORE', 'KORE', 'KRW', 0), 
       ('0TL/LIF', 'LIF', 'NOK', 1), 
...
```

Instead, Sybase requires classic ANSI-SQL with multiple `INSERT INTO` calls:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.contract_test ("CONTRACT_ID", "EXCHANGE_ID", "CURRENCY", "TRADING_CODE") 
VALUES ('0050/TAIEX', 'TAIEX', 'TWD', 0) 
INSERT INTO dbo.contract_test ("CONTRACT_ID", "EXCHANGE_ID", "CURRENCY", "TRADING_CODE") 
VALUES ('035420/KORE', 'KORE', 'KRW', 0)
INSERT INTO dbo.contract_test ("CONTRACT_ID", "EXCHANGE_ID", "CURRENCY", "TRADING_CODE") 
VALUES ('0TL/LIF', 'LIF', 'NOK', 1)
...
```

To resolve, instead of Pandas' convenient `to_sql` method, consider a direct SQLAlchemy `executemany` call with parameters using list of data frame rows via [`DataFrame.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy). Below assumes `contract_test` table always exists beforehand.

```
engine = create_engine(url)
sql = """INSERT INTO dbo.contract_test ("CONTRACT_ID", "EXCHANGE_ID", "CURRENCY", "TRADING_CODE") 
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"""

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(sql, df2.to_numpy().tolist())
```

If above still faces same issue, integrate a for-loop:

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    for row in df2.to_numpy().tolist():
        result = connection.execute(sql, row)
```

Comment: I have used the code as above suggested above, but getting below error :                   
result = connection.executemany(sql, row)
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'executemany'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Try running with `execute`. See edit. Docs indicate the DB-API will detect by parameters (list/tuple of iterables or just single iterable) when to use `executemany`.

Comment: It now works with execute, but is super slow and taking 12 mins to insert 4500 rows in the sybase database table. How to resolve this performance issue ?

Comment: Which version of `execute` (with or without for-loop)? Try a non-SQLAlchemy version with simple [pyodbc connection](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor). Use `cursor.executemany`.

Comment: It is still tremendously slow with pyodbc. I tried below combinations:                            1) pyodbc : execute and executemany     2) sqlalhemy : execute and executemany . Have tried both 1 and 2 with and without for loop. It is taking 9 minutes to insert 4500 rows. :(

Comment: Then issue may be your environment: either CPU client machine, databse configuration, or even ODBC driver. Are you connected by hard line to database via LAN? Or wireless on same network or remote network? Do you face other query performance issues beyond this append query?

Comment: Technically, the performane issue may be a different question as original error should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The [external SAP ASE (Sybase) dialect](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-sybase) is now the recommended SQLAlchemy dialect for Sybase, and it does support `fast_executemany` if you use the SAP ASE ODBC driver.